# How to wrap http.Request into proto file

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I need to wrap a http.Request into proto file so that I can send a request instance to the server side from client side, as the following code shows:

```
message WrapRequest{
  *http.Request request = 1; // this is wrong
  int64 start = 2;
  int64 stop = 3;
  bool match = 4;
  string ruleid = 5;
}
```

I'm sure the request line in my code is wrong, is there anyone who knows how to achieve it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: An `http.Request` isn’t really a thing that can serialized. What is the problem you’re trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to check the http request in agent side and if it is a dangerous request, I will send it to the server side via grpc. I need to serialize the request so that I can pass it and store it into mogodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can rather than pass the `http.Request` pass the `http.Request.Body` or `http.Request.Header` depends on what do you use on your server.

Comment: I add those fields in the struct manually to pass it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark as an answer.